# How to define one model property template for several models

Tags: dbt

I have a multiple models that are different SQL structure, but the output of the resulted tables will be always the same.
For example,
I have `modelA`, `modelB`, `modelC`, all the tables have columns called country and val.

```
# models/modelA.sql
select country, val from ...

# models/modelB.sql
select country, val from ...

# models/modelC.sql
select country, val from ...
```

so for the model property/schema file, I will have something like

```
# models/model_schema.yml
version: 2

models:
  - name: modelA
    description: "A starter dbt model A"
    columns:
      - name: country
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
      - name: val
        description: "value for the table"

  - name: modelB
    description: "A starter dbt model B"
    columns:
      - name: country
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
      - name: val
        description: "value for the table"

  - name: modelC
    description: "A starter dbt model C"
    columns:
      - name: country
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
      - name: val
        description: "value for the table"
```

Instead of having multiple models defined, as all the syntax, and the structure will be the same but only the model name will be different, but can I have only one 'template' or something similar such as following

```
# models/model_schema.yml
version: 2

models:
  - name: [modelA, modelB, modelC]
    tests: ...
    columns: ...
    meta: ...
```

The above is just an example.

In the actual works, the SQL queries are very complex and I would like to make a separate models.

I have tried to put Jinja template to fetch the models name and tried to make a macro, but I could not make it work. I followed some examples on https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros but not sure how I can implement on `.yml` for multiple models.
Could be something similar like that https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/2015 but I would like to implement for multiple model names.

Comment: Why not just make a model that UNION ALLs the other 3 together and put your tests on the new one? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AdamKipnis that's a good suggestion!
But each table is a bit complex and I would like to easily debug which table is especially failing when we do the test. Do you think if there is any other alternative solution to achieve this?

Comment: Still kind of hard to tell exactly what you're looking for. But some possible solutions for you to look at: 1) Create your own test macro that can be dropped into each of the 3 models as a test (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/tests#generic-tests). 2) There is a `codegen` package you can add that will generate sources, base models, etc (https://hub.getdbt.com/dbt-labs/codegen/latest/)

Comment: @AdamKipnis I've decided to simply use UNION ALL in this case, but I'll definitely take a look at `codegen`. Thanks again for your comment!